# Plugin - Social media share buttons

Tags: plugins

Is there a plugin with the social media share buttons where I have more control of where to place them?

At the moment, the only one's I can find only allow you to place the buttons at the top or bottom of pages/posts.

Ideally I'd like a snippet of code to just place wherever I wanted.

Comment: Most plugins that add the buttons automatically use the `the_content` filter to add there code,

you can remove that filter and create you own snippet based on that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came across one that wasn't over the top and there was also a manual function:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-social-bookmarking-light/